# Raising events in a BackgroundWorker.RunCompleted handler

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an instance of class `Foobar` that was constructed on thread X. I have a function `StartWork()` that should only be called from thread X. To avoid creating bugs I enforce this constraint by checking `Debug.Assert(CreatorID == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)`. The function starts the asynchronous operation of a `BackgroundWorker`. I've ensured that `WorkCompleted()` is called when the worker finishes its operations by hooking into `RunWorkerCompleted`.

For thread safety reasons `WorkCompleted()` should be executed on thread X, since it sends out event notifications. If these notifications are broadcast from the wrong thread, the program might run into unforeseen thread safety issues, I presume.

However, in my tests I noticed that `WorkCompleted()` isn't called from thread X as I expected. How can I fix my program to prevent any thread safety issues that may arise from these events being raised? Am I approaching the problem incorrectly? I'm already aware of the fact that I'll still need to make my `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` handler thread-safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raising an Event between 2 threads when neither thread is a WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853351/raising-an-event-between-2-threads-when-neither-thread-is-a-winform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler to run on the the same thread by creating the instance of `Foobar` on a UI thread. Relevant snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806824/217649):

> If the `BackgroundWorker` was created from the UI thread, then the `RunWorkerCompleted` event will also be raised on the UI thread.